# CococaPods: pod install crashes the machine

Tags: ruby, react-native, cocoapods, podspec

In my react-native project, I did remove `Podfile.lock` and `Pods` folder to re-install them due to some version conflict. Installing the pods for with two floowing approaches

1. `pod install` with or without `--repo-update` flag at ios folder
2. `bundle exec pod install --repo-update --project-directory=ios/` at
   root,

the process gets stuck at `generating pods project`, the
system slows down, and after some minutes system shuts
down/restarts.  **How should I troubleshoot what is going wrong?**

*Also if VSCode is open, the `code helper (renderer)` also get consumes high percentage of cpu when pod install starts*

[image]

```
System:
    OS: macOS 11.3
    CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8257U CPU @ 1.40GHz
    Memory: 308.68 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.15.4 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/node
    Yarn: 2.4.0 - ~/<projectPath>/node_modules/.bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.10 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.15.4/bin/npm
    Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.10.1 - /Users/amir/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: iOS 14.4, DriverKit 20.2, macOS 11.1, tvOS 14.3, watchOS 7.2
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
      System Images: android-26 | Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 4.0 AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763
    Xcode: 12.4/12D4e - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.2 - /Users/amir/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 17.0.1 => 17.0.1
    react-native: 0.64.0 => 0.64.0
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the flipper problem
I found the solution here
Running with --verbose showed me the library causing the problem, https://github.com/facebook/flipper/issues/2248#issuecomment-830060572 fixed it